# Is it allowed to express your frustration to Allah?

Tags: halal-haram, fiqh, sin

Salaam aleikum. Is it permissible to complain to Allah by pointing out your problems. Not in the sense that Allah does injustice, but to express to Allah the boredom, the trouble, the suffering, and the injustice that happens. Or to express your frustration to Allah about things that went wrong, bad in the past and things that went wrong, in the present and the future? Is there any risk of major kufr?

Answer (score 1):

Of course it is allowed.
Complaining to Allah (respectfully) is a part of dua.

For instance, Musa (AS) and his brother when they were told to go to the Pharoah complained about the danger:

> They said, ‘Lord, we fear he will do us great harm or exceed all bounds.’ (20:45)

Allah responds to them and reassures them:

> He said, ‘Do not be afraid, I am with you both, hearing and seeing everything.

And Yaqub (AS) complains to Allah about the sadness of losing his sons:

> And he turned away from them, saying, ‘Alas for Yusuf!’ His eyes went white with grief and he was filled with sorrow. [...]
>
> He said, "I only complain of my suffering and my grief to Allah, and I know from Allah that which you do not know. (12:86)

In fact, complaining to Allah about your situation is a form of worship because it shows the trust in Allah that He is Merciful and that He has the power to remove the problems. A hadith from the Prophet was narrated that he said:

> “Whoever is afflicted by a pressing need and complains to people, his need will never be satisfied. Whoever is afflicted by a pressing need and complains to Allah, eventually Allah will provide for him, sooner or later.” (Sunan al-Tirmidhī)

The etiquette is of course that you do not say anything wrong to Allah or disrespect Him, but only complain about your situation. If you do that, there is nothing wrong with it, and if He wills, Allah can fix your situation.